# How to implement dynamic gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

I have the following gridview with 8 imageview .

[image]

I want to delete one of the imageview . Then the gridview should be like the following :

[image]

How can I do this ? Any suggestion will be of great help .

Comment: a `GridView` is a `android.widget.AdapterView` so delete the data from your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots I can understand that `GridView` is populated with data by using adapter, and your requirement is to remove **History** `ImageView`.

Most probably it will be one of the `Collections(List/Set)` or may be an `Array`

from the `Collections` remove the value with **index 4** (position of History ImageView)

and finally notify your adapter that GridView values are changed. you can achieve this by using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method.